# Quelle est la nuance entre « Je n’ai rien prévu ce soir » et « Je n’ai rien de prévu ce soir »?

Tags: choix-de-mot, constructions

Je ne suis pas certain de la justesse des deux tournures. Et si les deux sont correctes sur tous les plans, laquelle devrais-je privilégier.

Merci

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Les deux sont utilisées pour exprimer que dans la soirée considérée rien qui s'y passera n'aura été prévu par la personne qui parle, tout au moins jusqu'au moment où elle parle. Cependant, la première phrase n'est pas d'un langage très élégant : ce que l'on dit par ces mots, selon la relation grammaticale de complément circonstanciel de temps, c'est « Pendant la présente soirée, jusqu'à maintenant, je n'ai pas encore prévu quelque chose » ; évidemment, le contexte qui correspond est très rare, ce qui se traduit par une utilisation quasi nulle de cette phrase selon cette signification et facilite son utilisation dans le contexte habituel expliqué ci-dessus. Une façon appropriée de pallier cette tournure peu élégante consiste à ajouter la préposition « pour ».

- Je n'ai rien prévu *pour* ce soir.

Comment: Je suis d’accord avec toi. Je te remercie encore!

Answer (score 5):

Dans "rien de prévu", *prévu* est un adjectif qui qualifie *rien*, tandis que dans "je n'ai rien prévu", *prévu* est une composante d'un verbe au passé composé, dont l'objet est *rien*. Leurs équivalents positifs sont "J'ai prévu quelque chose ce soir" et "j'ai quelque chose de prévu ce soir", ce qui révèle bien la différence structurelle.

Cette différence de syntaxe induit une légère différence de sens, puisque l'agent de prévoir est indéfini dans la deuxième phrase (Je n'ai rien de prévu = je n'ai rien qui ait été prévu, par qui que ce soit) tandis que c'est moi qui est l'agent de prévoir dans la première.

C'est pourquoi on utilise généralement "je n'ai rien de prévu" pour indiquer que son agenda est libre, qu'on n'a aucune obligation sur une période donnée, tandis que "je n'ai rien prévu" implique une part de responsabilité plus grande du sujet (par exemple, "les autorités n'avaient rien prévu pour consolider le pont dans les années qui ont précédé son effondrement).

Je ne perçois aucune différence de formalité entre les deux formulations.

Comment: Est-ce qu’il serait mieux d’ajouter « pour » à la phrase comme le recommande LPH, ou bien le sens en reste inchangé? Je tiens à préciser que ces mots sont prononcés le matin précédant ladite soirée, et non pas pendant la présente soirée, jusqu’à maintenant.

Comment: Je te remercie de m’avoir donné ton temps.